# Why doesn't {{#link-to 'home'}} refresh the page if i'm already on that linked page ('home')?

Tags: ember.js, hyperlink

For Ember.js, I have a link on my 'home' page inside the 'home page and in my website header i have a 
{{#link-to 'home'}}button{{/link-to}}.

What I thought (and what I want) is when clicking that {{#link-to}}, since it is on the linked page already, that it just refreshes the page, like most apps do.

Ex. in facebook, clicking the facebook icon will refresh the page, even if the user is already in the newsfeed.

Comment: I do not understand the question. Your app should refresh or not? What actually happens there? Note that there is a difference between `home` and `home.index` route that ember could create to you automatically. If would be nice to attach demo on jsbin etc.

Comment: You do realize you are in a single page app and there is no "refreshing of the page" going on right?

Comment: I can't do a demo at the moment but we shouldn't need one for this. The point is that i am on the home/about/whatever page and clicking a link to the page im already on. Right now i click that link to the page i'm on and nothing happens. I want the refresh.

Comment: @PatsyIssa I am not on a single page app and clicking a link to the page im on should refresh the page. It works like that for most other sites.

Comment: Are you using ember?

Comment: yes, that should be mentioned in the tags

Comment: Then it's a single page app....

Comment: Ember projects are not bound to single-page apps and this is not one, so let's move on

Comment: actualy it's bound to SPA. Why you want to refresh page what is your use case for this. you can transitonTo API in controller to achieve this behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The router will only transition to a new route if there is a non null transition to do. In you case you are transitionning to the same route, which result in a non transition and thus does nothing.

If you want to force a refresh of the page (which you should not and should try to find an alternatve solution), you can use window.location.reload() (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload).

Comment: And this adds to the large stack of major flaws with Ember. Every other website can do this. This answers my question though. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, how is this a major flaw? There is nothing to do. It is the same route with the same model.